# A function that gets a linked list and a number and changes the list so its made of couples that sum up to the given number

Tags: java, function, null

I need help writing a function that gets a linked list and a number and adds a node in between so every couple equals to the inserted number.
for example,

Original -

```
7 -> 10 -> 7 -> 15 -> 5 -> null
```

Number - 20

New list -

```
7 -> 13 -> 10 -> 10 -> 7 -> 13 -> 15 -> 5 -> 5 -> 15
```

In my code,

Instead of turning this list

```
7-->10-->7-->5-->15-->Null
```

into this

```
7 -> 13 -> 10 -> 10 -> 7 -> 13 -> 15 -> 5 -> 5 -> 15
```

I get this

```
7-->5-->Null
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
import java.util.*;
public class E3
{
    public static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void fillIn(Node<Integer> lst, int num)
    {
        Node<Integer> prev = lst;
        Node<Integer> next = lst.getNext();
        Node<Integer> fill = new Node<Integer>();
        while(lst.hasNext())
        {
            fill.setValue(num - prev.getValue());
            fill.setNext(prev.getNext());
            prev.setNext(fill);
            prev = next;
            if(next.getNext() == null)
            {
                fill.setValue(num - next.getValue());
                fill.setNext(null);
                prev.setNext(fill);
                return;
            }
            next = next.getNext();
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Node<Integer> n = new Node<Integer>(15);
        Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<Integer>(5, n);
        Node<Integer> n2 = new Node<Integer>(7, n1);
        Node<Integer> n3 = new Node<Integer>(10, n2);
        Node<Integer> n4 = new Node<Integer>(7, n3);
        System.out.println(n4);
        fillIn(n4, 20);
        System.out.println(n4);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a question? This is a bit broad currently. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and how does that compare with what is actually happening? It isn't clear what the problem is.